# Text extraction from bank like scanned cheque image using python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tesseract

I have n number of scanned bank cheque like templates.Each template's font size,font style differs..i need to extract text from each image using python opencv and tesseract library...How can i extract it?I am new to python and image processing. please help

Comment: What you have so far tried? You can easily find the code by google search. Try them , if you are getting any errors/issue please feel free to ask here. We are glad to help. Read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.